# Elasticsearch: How do you search scroll without HTTP 404 errors?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get all the documents from Elasticsearch for a search query that has 600k+ documents. You can not use the `search` `size` parameter or the index's `settings` that adjusts the max number of returned documents parameter because both of these expect a smaller number of documents.

From python elasticsearch module I do a:

```
result = client.search(... scroll='1m')
scroll_id = result['_scroll_id']
while True:
    # ...
    client.scroll(... scroll_id=scroll_id)
    # ...
```

The console reports successful scroll for like 200ms or about 7 scrolls. Then I get HTTP 404.

#### How do you search scroll without HTTP 404 errors?

p.s. i'm on version 7.3 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues/178

#### You have to modify your `client.scroll` call to include the `scroll` timeout parameter `scroll='1m'`:

```
client.search(... scroll='1m')
while True:
    # ...
    client.scroll(... scroll_id=scroll_id, scroll='1m')
```

Then my scrolling works.

p.s. I only use python here because it makes the writing easier (the solution was originally from a github for `R` programming language). This solution applies to any Elasticsearch REST API usage IMO.